# what is the default time duration for a double tap in iOS ?

Tags: ios, iphone

I would like to know the time taken to detect a double tap ie, the difference in time between both the taps to recognize it as a double tap in iOS. Is it hardware dependent ?

Comment: WHAT IS YOUR TAP SPEED?

Comment: Well my tap speed varies.What I really like to know is the tap speed that separates the single tap from double tap.

Answer (score -1):

To change the double tap speed, go to:

**Settings > General > Accessibility > VoiceOver > Double Tap Timeout.**  The default setting is .25 seconds.  Use the plus or negative symbol to adjust the double tap speed.